# Building programs in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

I always see these cool GitHub projects, but never an actual .exe file. So I read the README file, and it has a list of steps to "build" it. So building a program is when you create an .exe for some collection of files. But how do you build .exe files in Windows (10)? Is there a built-in program or do I need to download something?

Comment: "But how do you build .exe files in Windows (10)?" - The process to compile a program from source varies depending on the program. "is there a built-in program or do I need to download something?" - You need to download the compatiable compiler based on the specific program you want to compile.

Comment: As for the vote I issued.  [Here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [Here](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) are my reasons.

Comment: If you are asking "how to build the project" you should be using the pre-compiled package instead.  How you build a specific program is out of scope here at Superuser.  Outside of a problem with a specific tool, how you compile "any" program would also be out of scope (due to how broad that topic is).

Comment: Ok. Will edit and fix.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In most cases, you will need to have a set of development tools installed; which ones will depend on the particular project. It's conceivable that a project could be built in a scripting language that is inherently supported in Windows (e.g., JavaScript/ECMAScript, VBScript, Powershell), in which case you would not need to download anything; however, if it's written in a language like VB-for-Applications, you'd need the relevant application installed.

You can check the programming language the project is written in to tell whether or not you need a compiler, and which one to use if so. Alternatively, you could inquire with the author of the project as to what you need, or the availability of precompiled versions of the project.